# How to keep library dependencies updated to Scala version?

Tags: sbt

I am compiling my project with sbt and am getting an `UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES` error.

The fact is that I fetched the example I use (a hello world program) from an online blog, that uses `scalaVersion := "2.10.0"` as shown below. I am using 2.11.2.

How do I update the library dependencies (in the `build.sbt`) to the latest version of Scala, specifically the `revision` part?

**build.sbt**

```
name := "Hello Test #1"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.2-M1"
```

The error:

```
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11.2;2.2-M1 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11.2;2.2-M1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/plard/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11.2/2.2-M1/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.11.2/2.2-M1/akka-actor_2.11.2-2.2-M1.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.11.2/2.2-M1/akka-actor_2.11.2-2.2-M1.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11.2;2.2-M1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.11.2;2.2-M1: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 11, 2014 10:32:11 AM
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
name := "Hello Test #1"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.4"
```

This should do it. Note the `%%` and no version specified for the Akka artifact. Doing so, SBT will automatically append your Scala version to the artifact. See [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build.html) for more details.

Comment: Does this syntax works for any dependency i would like to add to the project? I.e. Is: '%% "name" % "reversion"' functions?

Comment: @wipman Yes, as long as the dependency artifact follow the "name_x.x" convention